# Firebase Crash not deobfuscating mapping file

Tags: firebase-crash-reporting

My app graddle is minify enabled and proguard is generating a mapping file.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.getBuildType().isMinifyEnabled()) {
            variant.assemble.doLast {
                copy {
                    from variant.mappingFile
                    into "${rootDir}/proguardTools"
                    rename { String fileName -> "mapping-${variant.name}-${versionName}.txt"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

Below dependencies code:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
//    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.2.1'
    releaseCompile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I've sent the generated mapping file to firebase crash in deobfuscation file area, to the righ version, but the error log is not deobfuscated.

The Firebase crash show me the log like below example:

> Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.db.c()' on a null object reference
>
> com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.cz.onClick (cz.java:3055)
> android.view.View.performClick (View.java:5716)
> android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:22596)
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
> android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
> android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7325)
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)

This log doesn't indicate where the error occurred.

I think this log is not deobfuscated, right?

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: Your mapping file it is to deobfuscated your own app, but this error is in the maps library which is also obfuscated.
I am having the same problem, did you find the problem?

Comment: Not yet. I reduce the occurences of this erros upgrading Google Services where has some bugs, but i dont have a solution to firebase crash show me the exact point where my app crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Deobfuscation happens for all crashes that occur *after* the mapping file was uploaded.  It does not affect existing prior crashes that were collected in the dashboard.

Comment: I understand, but even the errors collected after the mapping file is sent are not showing details as to where exactly the error occurred.

Comment: Then you might want to contact troubleshooting support to help figure out what's going wrong. https://firebase.google.com/support/